# mathematica returned imaginary number for x^(2/3)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

```
N[(-27)^(2/3)]//returns -4.5+7.79423i
```

what would be the reason Mathematica returned an imaginary number for x^(2/3) when x= -27?

it should be 9

I think this is not a bug, but I do not understand the reason

Comment: Please don't post code and output as images. Click [edit] and add it as text, even if you have to type it out by hand.

Comment: @IMSoP edited, :)

Comment: Why do you think the answer should be zero?

Comment: actually, it should be 9, @MarkPattison, but the point here is its should not be an imaginary number

Comment: good explanation [here](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-27-2-3-not-allowed) on your exact problem.

Comment: Further to DTul's comment : `((-27)^2)^(1/3)` yields 9

Answer (score 0):

when you find (-27)^(2/3) you acutely solve the equation x^(3
/2) + 27 = 0, and this equation gives some imaginary solutions, which you have one of them in your case.